# Vaadin Flow: How to tell if a Component is attached

Tags: dom, vaadin, vaadin-flow

How does one reliably find out if a given `Component` is actually present in the `DOM`?

Until now I used [Component.getUI().isPresent()](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0.rc4/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html#getUI--) which is supposed to able to determine if the `Component` is attached to a `UI`.

It also might be that I ran into an edge case as the `Components` in question are encapsulated in a `ComponentRenderer` which is managed by a `Grid`.

I need to access these `Componets` via JavaScript like this:

```
void setValue(Component comp, Value value){
  Runnable callJs = comp.getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.getPage().executeJs("someCall($0)", value));

  if(comp.isAttached()){
    // execute it right away
    callJs.run();
  } else {
    // execute onAttach
    comp.addAttachListener(evt -> callJs.run());
  }
}
```

Comment: If you need to initialize the component using JavaScript, you can call `executeJavascript` from its attach listener.

Comment: I added a sample method to illustrate the problem. If I add an `AttachListener` while the `Component` is already attached it does not effect it right away. And if it is not attached yet i would make an unnecessary JS call over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I stumbled across the [StateNode](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.0.rc6/com/vaadin/flow/internal/StateNode.html) API:

```
comp.getElement().getNode().isAttached()
```